# jQuery works in fiddle, but not when LIVE?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying a simple jQuery test
*simple HTML table with input checkboxes
*jQuery to kick out some data when any of the check boxes are clicked.

It seems to work in fiddle.net just fine..: http://jsfiddle.net/UBVwL/

but when I make a 'test' page with just this stuff in it..  it doesnt work?  What could I be missing and/or doing wrong here?

jQuery:

```
$('.orderTable').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
    console.log(group);
});
```

Basic HTML:

```
<body>
<table class="orderTable">
    <tr>
        <td class="optionClass testimonialCell"><label><input id="testimonial" name="TestimonialHistory" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Testimonial History</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="optionClass challengesCell"><label><input id="challenges" name="Challenges" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Challenges</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="optionClass licenseCell"><label><input id="statelincensediscipline" name="StateLicenseDiscipline" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;State License Discipline</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="optionClass articleswrittenCell"><label><input id="articleswritten" name="ArticlesWritten" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Expert Written Articles </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="optionClass articlesNameingCell"><label><input id="articlesnaming" name="ArticlesNaming" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Articles Naming Expert</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

This is what I have in the head: (where jQuery code is)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>


<head>
<title>Some Title</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>

//what version of jQuery is being loaded
alert("JQ version: " + $.fn.jquery);
console.log("JQ version: " + $.fn.jquery);

$('.orderTable').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
}
console.log(group);
});
</script>

</head>
```

I have tried several other approaches as well... but none seem to work when NOT in jsfiddle.net  :(

Alt example 1:

```
$("input").click(function () {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
}
console.log('clicked');
});
```

Alt example 2:

```
$('.orderOptions').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[id='" + $(this).attr("id") + "']";
    //var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
} else {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
}
console.log(group);
});
```

Comment: use document ready handler or set code once element is in DOM. In jsFiddle, you wrapped code inside onload handler

Comment: Are you testing this by loading it from a server, or are you just opening the file locally with your browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

youre missing

```
$(function(){  // DOM IS NOW READY

    /* YOUR CODE HERE */

});
```

[jQuery docs .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code is in your `<head>`. At the time this code is processed, the HTML elements are not there. You have to delay the execution. Wrap your code in

```
jQuery(document).ready (function (){ 
    // your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing this in a standalone file on your filesystem, you'll want to update your script tag to indicate the scheme (http/s):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, jQuery will fail to load.

Comment: Good catch. Just as a side-note `localhost` WILL work, it's only if the document is loaded from `file://` than it'll not work.